# json style mongodb php query

Tags: php, json, mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to create mongodb query using json format like I do in studio 3T.

For example i exceute this "where" in studio 3t and it works fine

```
{ $and: [ { "message": { $not: /.*status=sent.*/i } }, { "message": { $not: 
/.*status=bounce.*/i } }, { "message": { $not: /.*message-id.*/i } } ] }
```

But I don't know how to use it in php.

I can create queris this way:

```
public function connect(...)
{
   ...
   self::$connect = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://'.$data);
} 

public function query($table, $filter = array(), $options = array())
{
     if(!self::$connect)
     {
         self::$connect = $this->connect();
     }

     $query = new \MongoDB\Driver\Query(
                $filter, // query (empty: select all)
                $options // options, example: ['limit' => 40 ]
     );
     return self::$connect->executeQuery($this->dbName.'.'.$table, $query); 
}


$result = $mongo->query('messages', $filter, array('limit' => 1000));
```

**How to make it using json-style ?**